# InfoPath form after submit shows same data for different input

Tags: infopath-data-connections

I have a Infopath Form which is list based modified and having a submit button with 4 fields . `Prjct_id`, `Prjct_Nm`, `Prjct_Dt`, `Phase_id`.

On entering `prjct_id` and `Phase_id` and click on button the data is populated and saved to list. Data connection is used (REST Web service) here to get data.It is working fine when i enter valid `prjct_id` and `phase_id`.

I am able to get the data and submitted to list but if I am entering wrong `prjct_id` and `phase_id` it shows the same data of previously submitted id . How to make it avoided when i enter invalid `prjct_id` and `phase_id` it should not show any data .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it after so many tweaks. Added a button and set values to the fields to make them empty . One more thing is while querying the data in rule I have set the query for data after I change the rest web service url. It resolved my issue.Thanks.